# Can't access to win 10 after installing Ubuntu on 2nd disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I currently have two ssd disks. On one, there's windows 10 installed and the other disk was free. Decided to install Ubuntu on the 2nd disk, but now my pc doesn't detect my old OS.

I tried changing the boot settings, but on my bios I can't seem to find the old partition [image]

At this point I thought that all my old stuff was deleted, but on the file explorer I can see them

[image]

This being the Ubuntu disk [image]

And this being the old Windows part [image]

One of the fixes I tried with no luck (grub doesn't even start) was [this one](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-ubuntu-not-detecting-windows-10-partition-during-install/). Dunno if it would be of any help, but lsblk showed me this [image].

One thing I noted here is that nvme0n1 lacks a boot part?

Comment: In the terminal lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID or lsblk -f. For convenience, you can install sudo apt install grub-customizer

Comment: Do not post screenshots of terminal output. Just post output & format it. Also no need to post loop devices, they just are all your snaps. `lsblk -e 7 -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint,parttype` Better to see lots of details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair